# groupby and filter pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

df:

```
    make    country other_columns   sale
honda   tokyo   data    1
honda   hirosima    data    0
toyota  tokyo   data    1
toyota  hirosima    data    0
suzuki  tokyo   data    0
suzuki  hirosima    data    0
ferrari tokyo   data    1
ferrari hirosima    data    0
nissan  tokyo   data    1
nissan  hirosima    data    0
```

Condition:
keep pairs that have 1,0

desired output

```
make    country other_columns   sale
honda   tokyo   data    1
honda   hirosima    data    0
toyota  tokyo   data    1
toyota  hirosima    data    0
ferrari tokyo   data    1
ferrari hirosima    data    0
nissan  tokyo   data    1
nissan  hirosima    data    0
```

What i tried (which is obviously not working )

```
outdf = df.groupby('sale').filter(lambda x: x > 0)
```

should i be grouping both the columns ('sale' and 'make')?

Comment: a pair is make + 2 state?

Comment: just make, but i would need all the columns

Comment: @AntonvBR edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using `groupby` + `set`. This should be extendable and does not require ordering:

```
s = df.groupby('make')['sale'].apply(set)
res = df[df['make'].map(s) >= {0, 1}]

print(res)

      make   country other_columns  sale
0    honda     tokyo          data     1
1    honda  hirosima          data     0
2   toyota     tokyo          data     1
3   toyota  hirosima          data     0
6  ferrari     tokyo          data     1
7  ferrari  hirosima          data     0
8   nissan     tokyo          data     1
9   nissan  hirosima          data     0
```

Answer (score 6):

Indeed, you need `groupby` but on the column 'make' and you can use `filter` with a function creating a `tuple` from 'sale' column:

```
outdf = df.groupby('make').filter(lambda x: tuple(x.sale)== (1,0))
```

and you get the expected output:

```
      make   country other_columns  sale
0    honda     tokyo          data     1
1    honda  hirosima          data     0
2   toyota     tokyo          data     1
3   toyota  hirosima          data     0
6  ferrari     tokyo          data     1
7  ferrari  hirosima          data     0
8   nissan     tokyo          data     1
9   nissan  hirosima          data     0
```

if the order between 1 and 0 is not always satisfy for a same 'make', you can use a `sort_values` on 'sale' column first

Comment: yea this is what i needed